# Java IndexArrayOutOfBounds issue

Tags: java, bukkit

So I have some code which gives an error when executing...

```
        if (!(sender.hasPermission("nexodus.an"))) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You can not do this command!");
            return true;
        } else if (args.length == 0) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " You must specify a predetermined message to broadcast!");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " 1: Server Restarting");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " 2: Login servers are currently down!");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " 3: Reloading for GameModes");
            return true;
        } else if (args.length > 1) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " NexodusMC will be restarting in 5 seconds.");
            } else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("2")) { 
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Login servers are currently down. Logging off my prevent you from getting back on, sorry!");
//Line above is line 53 ||
            } else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.BLACK + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "NexodusMC" + ChatColor.BLACK + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Server reload due to adding/removing/editing gamemodes!");
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Here is my error log.

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'an' in plugin NexodusHub vSwag
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46)
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:192)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:523)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:959)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.PlayerConnection.chat(PlayerConnection.java:877)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:834)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.Packet3Chat.handle(SourceFile:49)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:296)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.PlayerConnection.e(PlayerConnection.java:116)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.ServerConnection.b(SourceFile:37)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.DedicatedServerConnection.b(SourceFile:30)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:592)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.DedicatedServer.t(DedicatedServer.java:227)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:488)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:421)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:583)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at me.Bling.NexodusMain.Main.onCommand(Main.java:53) # 53 is the error line.

        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
        ... 15 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed**

Changed

```
} else if (args.length > 1) {
```

to

```
} else if (args.length > 0) {
```